Proving $\sin(A/2)\sin(B/2)\sin(C/2)\le 1/8$, where $A+B+C=\pi$
I found this sort of trigonometric inequality on a book. What is the easiest way to prove it?

If $A+B+C=\pi$, prove $\sin(A/2)\sin(B/2)\sin(C/2)\le 1/8$.

I almost have no clue about where to start with this one.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Is it also given that $A,,B,,C\ge0$? If so, exploit the fact $\ln\sin x$ is concave.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... Even when you're completely stumped, you can provide useful context to people who might assist you. Since you found the inequality in a book, perhaps there are other relevant results in there that would help. Sometimes, just "thinking out loud" about things you know can get you going, and it can help others avoid explaining things you already understand, as well as give a sense of what you consider "easy". (Please provide any context or other information in the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) Good luck!

Sorry I don't know anything beyond basic trigonometry and polynomials in pure math.I thought there can be a simple a solution for instance like sinA+sinB+sinc=4cosA/2cosB/2cosC/2 if A+B+C=pi

Well,I consider solving usual trigonometric identities easy and I know garphs of trig ratios and their values in different quadrants.tI know basics about inqualities too.
